# mod_rewrite redirects for site root and subdirectory from HTTP to SSL

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, mod-rewrite, directory

Ok, so I have two sites within the same webroot — the main site (in the root) and an unrelated bunch of files in a subdirectory. We would like both of these sites to force rendering under SSL.

At the moment, the relevant chunks of my `httpd.conf` read as follows:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^subdir(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/subdir$1 [R=301,L]

            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory "/var/www/html/subdir">
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine on

        <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^subdir(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/subdir$1 [R=301,L]

            RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
        </IfModule>
    </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

but if a user browses directly to `http://www.domain.com/subdir`, they get redirected to the site root (`https://www.domain.com/`), discarding the rest of the request path. This is the case even if I remove the whole `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` section from the subdirectory's `<Directory>` section and is also the case if I remove the first `RewriteCond`/`RewriteRule` pair in each config section (which we only added to try to fix this problem).

I can't see why the first rule (in either `<Directory>` section) isn't taking effect first, so that the user is immediately redirected to `https://www.domain.com/subdir` (with SSL and `subdir`) before `mod_rewrite` even gets to the second rule (in either section).

I presume I'm doing something obviously wrong (not least because Apache configuration is not my core skillset), but I just can't see it. Looking at the [`mod_rewrite` docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) and the docs on [How configuration sections are merged](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/sections.html#mergin) doesn't seem to answer my question either, unless I'm reading them wrong, so I'm at a complete loss.

Can anyone see the (probably obvious) mistake I'm making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the intent with the second `RewriteRule` under the subdir to send the user to the root, dropping the subdir path?

The context of the string passed to your source regex is dependent on the `<Directory>` context - so a request to `/subdir/something.html` will give the `/var/www/html` rules a string of `subdir/something.html` to match against, while the rules within `/var/www/html/subdir` will be matching against `something.html`.

You can use `RewriteBase` to override the context, so the config can be fixed to work as intended in one of two ways; using a `RewriteBase`:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/subdir">
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteBase /
    # ... etc etc, no other changes needed
```

..or, by changing the destination URL to take the context into account (first rule will never match, as `subdir` isn't in the string):

```
<Directory "/var/www/html/subdir">
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/subdir/$1 [R=301,L]
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</Directory>
```

Comment: The intention is to redirect any HTTP path to the same path under SSL (so `http://domain.com/` -> `https://domain.com/` and `http://domain.com/subdir/` -> `https://domain.com/subdir/`). So `RewriteBase` would "fix" that the first rule in the `subdir` is currently irrelevant, but also would solve that my problem seems to be the second rule, as you mention in your second example. Hopefully, that means I can give you a shiny green tick when I get to the office in the morning; thank you!  ;o)

Comment: That was exactly the problem I was having and your second example fixed it. Thank you, Shane!

Comment: @OwenBlacker, for the reasons listed in [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9105894/372643), I'd actually avoid this sort of redirections.

Comment: @Bruno That's actually a very good point, in cases of sites where the client system may send any kind of sensitive data - though `POST` parameters would be lost in the redirect, causing breakage in those cases, and sensitive session cookies could be set to secure-only.. but yeah, a better approach may be to only set the site or subdirectory's entry point (`^/$` or `^/subdir/firstpage.html$`) and 403 or 404 the rest.

Comment: Interesting, and I'd not thought of that. As it happens, on our site, it's very unlikely to be a problem (we'll be forcing users to come from specific known referrers and the whole site requires login, so it does mean that users are unlikely ever to suffer that problem. I might go and make that change on Monday nonetheless, in any case. Thank you both for pointing that out!